# Implementation in C++ to aes256

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, aes

recently i try use a gladman library for aes-256(http://www.gladman.me.uk/), i get work encryption and decryption in ecb, but the problem is i can't get the same result what other tool (for example a online tool), i use the ecb mode in length of 32 bits.

```
AESencrypt encriptador; //class encrypt

unsigned char *keymain=new unsigned char[256]; // in this lines i probe putt the value of password in the begin or end of array, but i dong't get the correct answer.
                                    //
memset(keymain,0,sizeof(char)*256);//

keymain[0]= 61;

AESdecrypt desencriptador; //class decrypt

encriptador.key(  keymain, 256 ); // assign the key the member id definited by library of gledman
desencriptador.key( keymain, 256 ); //

unsigned char *ab= new unsigned char[88];

unsigned char *ac= new unsigned char[88];

memset(ab, 0, 88*sizeof(char));
memset(ac, 0, 88*sizeof(char));

unsigned char *ad=new unsigned char[44];

char *az=new char[4];
memset(az, 0, (sizeof(char)*4));
az[0]='c';
az[1]='o';
az[2]='n';

memset(ad, 0, (44*sizeof(char)));

cout<<"cadena de ejemplo"<<az<<endl;
encriptador.ecb_encrypt( reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(az), ab, 32); //ecb_encrypt is definited by gledman library, az is buffer enter, and ab is buffer exit.

QByteArray arreglo=QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ab));

qDebug()<<"cadena en base64: "<<arreglo.toBase64();
qDebug()<<"cadena en hexadecimal: "<<arreglo.toHex();

desencriptador.ecb_decrypt(ab, ac, 32); //ecb_decrypt is definited by gledman library, ab is buffer enter and ac is buffer out

cout<<"su cadena original debe ser: "<<ac<<endl; //i get the original string but i    don't get the same value with other tool
```

Well, i get the file of answers for key and values knows, but i can't change the sive of block.

Comment: You do know that you don't need all of those calls to `new[]`?  Just declare a good, old-fashioned array.

Comment: What do you mean "same result"? You mean the other tool cannot decrypt it? Or that the encrypted version is not identical?

Comment: Is it possible that an encyrpted string can contain embedded NULL bytes?  If so, then you are using `QByteArray` incorrectly here: `QByteArray arreglo=QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ab));`  You should be calling the constructor that has the size of the data as the second parameter, otherwise `QByteArray` constructor that you're using will stop at the first null byte.

Comment: well, when i say not same result i refer to hex value showed of encrypted string vs the hex value of string encrypted with a online tool (i don't know, but i can put a link here?)
For example my program for key with value 1 and text value c(i give two value as hex same in the web page), give hex value: 
0e6a1f699a7bd34a440e1ea1902c85784e964e58881958364716f262340a4fea

one web page says hex value : 
197a08e06a167da9f8b8846a1d6248d4fbab82aef2cefeb91ca7203964c73e07

Comment: my problem is encrypted string is not equal to other implementations, or maybe it's normal, because i probe in openssl command line and get other values YxGnszkF1GoOtdjVljl4sg== (this is in base64)

one web page says hex value : 
197a08e06a167da9f8b8846a1d6248d4fbab82aef2cefeb91ca7203964c73e07

Comment: If `az` is only 4 bytes, how can you use it for a block encrypt of 32 bytes? And if it is only 4 bytes, why would you use 2 16 byte blocks?

Comment: well, this library is "dark"(not exist more documentation the and my key is arbitrary (in value and length), and i use 216 bytes for requirement.

Comment: well, i revise documentation and works good with 128 key, and block of 128, the problem is the aes256 is key of 256 and block size of 256, i can't change the block size, someone know how do?

Comment: AES with a block size of 256 does not exist, you need to use a Rijndael implementation instead. AES is a subset of Rijndael with key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 and a block size of 128 bit.

Comment: hi, thanks, in the tests of library appears aes block size of 256( the test are in C, but i never get work with their block size from C++), finally i decided change the library, now with this new library works ok.